# DDLog(CocoaLumberjack) message in console

Tags: ios, logging, cocoalumberjack

I want to replace **NSLog** with  **CocoaLumberjack**, and I follow the [GettingStarted](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaLumberjack/wiki/GettingStarted), then add

```
DDLogError(@"This is an error.");
DDLogWarn(@"This is a warning.");
DDLogInfo(@"This is just a message.");
DDLogVerbose(@"This is a verbose message.");
```

but why there is no log message in XCode's console?

Comment: Did you set your log level?  Did you setup the DDTTYLogger?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Lumberjack is a generic logging framework. You have to config it to use one (or more) specific log outputs. E.g., for Apple's console, you have to use:

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDASLLogger sharedInstance]];
```

For terminal:

```
[DDLog addLogger:[DDTTYLogger sharedInstance]];
```

Comment: Actually, in his case, DDTTYLogger

Comment: @borrrden: You are right, `DDASLLogger`goes to Apple console. I edit my answer.

Answer (score 2):

DDASLLogger is deprecated as of iOS 10.

You should use DDOSLogger

`ddlog.add(DDOSLogger.sharedInstance)`